# Problems returning data with Angular httpClient

Tags: angular, http, get, observable

Hi I have a simple controller that returns a simple (I’ve simplified it all for this post):

```
  [HttpGet("[action]")]
  public AppSettings GetStuff()
  {
        var stuff = new Stuff { Dummy = ”Hi”; };
        return stuff;
  }

  public class Stuff
  {
    public string Dummy { get; set; }
  }
```

All good, now I call it from my Angular service:

```
getStuff(): Observable<IStuff> {
    return (this.httpClient
        .get<IStuff>(this.localUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandlerSerevice.handleError)
        )) as any;
}
```

Here’s my IStuff:

```
export interface IStuff {
    Dummy?: string;
}
```

All good…
The console shows me 200 and the response…

But when I subscribe to getStuff() from my component I get [object object] or udentified…
I have tried a god few subscriptions but no luck:

```
stuff: IStuff;

getStuff(){
    this.stuffService.getStuff()
        .subscribe(stuff => this.stuff = stuff); 
}
Or:
getStuff(){
    this.stuffService.getStuff()
        .subscribe((data: IStuff) => this.stuff = {
            Dummy: data['Dummy']
        });
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting `[object object] or udentified`? On the console? Where exactly did you log the response?

Comment: The console returns the json object as expected. I get the undefined during the subscription binding: stuff => this.stuff = stuff, Or when stepping through the code and hovering over data['Dummy'].

Comment: If I do this for instance .subscribe(data => {
                this.stuff = data;
                alert(data); 
            }); 
I get [Object Object]....

Comment: That's because `alert` will call `toString()` on your object, which will result in `[Object object]`. If you want the JSON format, you'll need to call `JSON.stringify` yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
instance .subscribe(data => { this.stuff = data; alert(data); });
```

You're trying to print `data` on an alert box. But since `data` is a JavaScript Object, you're seeing `[Object object]` as the alert will call `toString` on it. If you want the actual contents to be printed, you'll have to `stringify` it.

Try this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This should print the actual response.